# Bind html to angular-ui-bootstrap accordion

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using the angular-ui-bootstrap accordion. And I'm in a `ng-repeat`.
In my accordion heading I'm trying to bind to a scope variable with html in it.
I'm trying to bind the html with `data-ng-bind-html` and the angular `$sce` service. 
I've also injected `ngSanitize` in my app.js.

But I don't get the result I want.
 This is my accordion heading:

```
<accordion close-others="true">
        <accordion-group class="row" data-ng-repeat="content in pageContent" data-ng-if="content.pageId === page.id">
            <accordion-heading data-ng-bind-html="trustedHtml(content.columnTitle)" ></accordion-heading>
            <!-- rest of content -->
       </accordion-group>
      </accordion>
```

In my controller I inject `$sce` and this is the `$scope` method:

```
$scope.trustedHtml = function (input) {

        return $sce.trustAsHtml(input);
    }
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing the following,

In HTML,

```
<accordion close-others="true">
   <accordion-group class="row" data-ng-repeat="content in pageContent" data-ng-if="content.pageId === page.id">
     <accordion-heading ng-bind-html="content.columnTitle | unsafe" ></accordion-heading>
            <!-- rest of content -->
   </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

In Javascript,

```
app.filter('unsafe', function($sce) {
  return function(val) {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
  }; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this with a controller and model why not use a directive template. Pass the variable to the template. Extract it's value and then give it as the replace value inside of your directive.

Comment: i'm in a ng-repeat: i've adjusted the html sample code above just a minute ago

Comment: You can still use a custom directive and template. Put the directive on the accordion-heading tag, pass the scope variable name with the directive, get the scope value in the directive and set element.html to the stored value. It's a stylistic thing but I prefer this way over the others as I want to keep all DOM manipulations out of the controller, factory, etc. and only in directives. Also, since this is what a directive is designed for you no longer have to worry about getting Angular to recognize it's actually supposed to be inserting HTML.

Comment: hi, thanks for your response. I've tried your suggestion, but i'm still struggling. I think it's because i'm putting a directive on a (bootstrap-ui accordion) directive